# Joining GTA V online error

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

After starting GTA V (Xbox One) and after choosing play online I get this message on the screen: "Could not download files from the Rockstar Games service to play GTA Online" , after accepting it it starts to load online again but same message appears. It appeared from one day to an other and can't play now for more than a week, I use cable to connect to internet so it can't be connection issues. What can be the problem?

Comment: "I use cable to connect to internet so it can't be connection issues" That is very far from the truth

Comment: Okay I mean not wifi that can cause some trouble if the sign is weak, plus other games works fine online

Comment: Try reinstalling your game. Also, what is your NAT type (Xbox network settings)?

Comment: My NAT type is set to open, tried changing the DNS settings as well but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to go online by using a different network (mobile hotspot) and after switching back to original network it kept working. Probably there was some trouble with my open ports on the original networks router.

Answer (score 1):

This was an error message that occurred worldwide for all players of GTA Online for about a week, when the servers were shut down due to an unnamed bug in the Casino Heist update/DLC code. The bug was fixed, and GTAO should work normally now (at least until they find another bug...)